# What is the reason for the different order of the Source and Destination in a L2 header?

Tags: ethernet, ipv4, tcp, protocol-theory, udp

A TCP/UDP header (Layer 4) lists the **Source** Port, then the **Destination** Port:

[image: TCP and UDP Header]

An IP header (Layer 3) lists the **Source** IP, then the **Destination** IP:

[image: IPv4 Header]

An Ethernet header (L2) and a WiFi Header (L2) lists the ***Destination*** MAC then the **Source** MAC:

[image: Ethernet and WiFi Header]

## My question

Is there a reason for the switching of the Source and Destination in the L2 headers? If so, what is the reason?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The roots of the two technologies just are not really related.

When Bob Metcalfe, et al. were creating ethernet, they were not working with Vint Cerf, et al. who were creating IP. These were two completely separate efforts. When ethernet was created, it was not at all clear that IP would become dominant, and ethernet was just one of several LAN technologies that was vying for attention. IP didn't get on ethernet for a relatively long period of time because IP was originally connecting universities across the country using WAN technologies.

Eventually, the market forces preferred the two technologies, and they ended up the dominant technologies in their respective niches, but, although they were both conceived (1970s) and born around the same time period (ethernet in 1980, and RFC 791 in 1981), they actually didn't have much to do with each other until the 1990s, and they are still maintained by completely separate standards organizations.

Comment: One important aspect to the L2 ordering with the destination MAC first is the lower latency to read bits earlier in the frame and perform cut through switching. The order is less important in higher layer protocols.

Comment: @generalnetworkerror I doubt cut through switching was a motivation when Ethernet was defined, but ease of filtering received packets at the NIC may well have been.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have a source for it, but I'm pretty sure that the Ethernet creators wanted to let hardware devices decide as soon as possible whether they wanted to receive a frame or not - remember that early Ethernet used a shared bus which means each frame is received by every node in the network and Ethernet has always been hardware-based.

The destination MAC in front also comes in handy for switching, but that was invented many years later than Ethernet.

In contrast, IP is a protocol that was conceived as running in software. A packet is "somehow" received (IP doesn't care) and only then it is processed by the IP stack. It simply doesn't matter where the destination address is located.

Of course, today a lot of IP processing goes on in hardware as well, but when it was designed that wasn't really imaginable.

Comment: I certainly remember discussing hardware switching algorithms for ethernet circa 1985, and we considered the destination-first ordering a distinct advantage for implementation in devices such as programmable array logic where each bit of storage was valuable.  I'm sure the ethernet designers would have been conscious of any possibility of a benefit.

Comment: @jonathanjo Are you sure that was 1985? The PALs and GALs back then would've filled quite a large board for a (small) switch. The first commercial switch came 1990 from Kalpana and it used modular ports that where similar to NICs.

Comment: I had a pair of Kalpana switches that we bought before Cisco swallowed the company. They would do 10 Mbps full duplex, had VLANs, and I think it was three interfaces dedicated to channeling that I used to connect the switches to each other. If I remember correctly, each had 10 interfaces.

Comment: I guess they had 12 interfaces (other than the three that could be used for channeling), so maybe I'm remembering that we used 10 interfaces on each switch. Each switch interface went to a stack of hubs for the VLAN we put for the switch interface. Breaking up the huge broadcast domain really helped a lot. I'm pretty sure this was what we had: http://ciscoarchive.lunaimaging.com/luna/servlet/detail/CHMC~4~4~19~218:Kalpana-EtherSwitch?sort=date%2Ctype%2Ctitle&qvq=w4s:/who%2FKalpana%2Fwhat%2Fswitch%2FRouter;sort:date%2Ctype%2Ctitle&mi=0&trs=1

Comment: Can't say that I've worked with them but the very first switch was the EPS-700 I can't find a photo for. The successor EPS-1500's back can be seen here: http://www.edugeek.net/attachments/forums/general-chat/42220d1489755803-any-tech-spotters-xc8nznyy.jpg

Comment: @zac67 ... quite certain it was between 1984 and 1987, when I worked at a particular engineering firm.  We didn't build anything, but we discussed cross-chip routing/switching algorithms based on devices such as Monolithic Memory's "PAL" range of chips, which we used very frequently.  We'd often do back-of-envelope designs to work out how big and fast something would be: completely agree with you about how big an ether switch would have been.  We certainly thought dst-first was highly beneficial when you're fighting for each gate.

Comment: @jonathanjo Very impressive, I made my first steps with TTL chips back then. ;-)

Comment: @Zac67 ... and conversely, once a packet was accepted, memory-mapped IO buffers would give essentially flat access to IP headers, so field order was unimportant even if we fretted about byte-ordering.  Though we used TCP/IP internally, we knew of no UK or European organisations outside UCL etc with long-haul internet.  At that time the dominant cost was the last-mile wire, with high per-minute charges and our 1200-baud modem, used for e-mail over uucp, was something like £300.  As Ron says above, we didn't really see much overlap in the problems of ether and IP.